# MVC 5 sending Integer to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to update a model from a model. The value is an integer in both models. I know how to pass the text fields but I am having trouble passing the integer. below is what I am trying to accomplish.

So when I add a webpage this will create the navigation model.

I am trying to send this to the model.

```
LiColumn = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumn), **// needs to be integer**
LiColumnOrder = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumnOrder), **// needs to be integer**
```

And this is the GetModel code:

```
public override object GetModel(Navigation widget)
    {
        var masterPages = GetPages(null);
        var childPages = widget.IncludeChildren ? GetPages(masterPages) : new List<Webpage>();
        var navigationRecords =
            masterPages.Where(webpage => webpage.Published).OrderBy(webpage => webpage.DisplayOrder)
                   .Select(webpage => new NavigationRecord
                   {
                       LiText = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.Name),
                       LiUrl = MvcHtmlString.Create("/" + webpage.LiveUrlSegment),
                       LiColumn = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumn), **// needs to be integer**
                       LiColumnOrder = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumnOrder), **// needs to be integer**
                       Children = childPages.Where(webpage1 => webpage1.ParentId == webpage.Id)
                                        .Select(webpage1 =>
                                                new NavigationRecord
                                                {
                                                    LiText = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage1.Name),
                                                    LiUrl = MvcHtmlString.Create("/" + webpage1.LiveUrlSegment),
                                                    LiColumn = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumn), **// needs to be integer**
                                                    LiColumnOrder = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumnOrder) **// needs to be integer**
                                                }).ToList()
                   }).ToList();

        return new NavigationList(navigationRecords.ToList());
    }
```

So my question is how do I send this using something other than `MvcHtmlString` Cannot convert from integer to string.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No i did not, I am sorry. :(

Comment: Why not add a ToString() on your integer variable if the MvcHtmlString.Create is having trouble with the conversion?

Comment: I was thinking this might work, Havnt tested yet. 'LiColumn = ((int)(webpage.NavColumn)),'

Comment: if that does not work i will make it string and use dropdown to set to a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

OK for anyone that needs this, here is what i did. worked great. Not positive it is the proper way. If anyone has a better way or can improve on this please do.

I changed this:

```
LiColumn = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumn), **// needs to be integer**
LiColumnOrder = MvcHtmlString.Create(webpage.NavColumnOrder), **// needs to be integer**
```

To this:

```
LiColumn = ((int)(webpage.NavColumn)),
LiColumnOrder = ((int)(webpage.NavColumnOrder)),
```